# Bootstrap dynamic slider in Laravel image is not showing

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, slider

I am trying to implement bootstrap carousel dynamically from input in Laravel. My slider is working properly but the image is not showing.

slider code

```
@foreach($sliders as $key => $slider)
        <div class="carousel-item {{$key == 0 ? 'active' : '' }}">
            <img src="{{url('images/slider-rms', $slider->image)}}" class="d-block w-100"  alt="..."> 
        </div>
        @endforeach
```

The backend and slider is working fine. But I am not sure about the path.

The image folder is : *public->images->slider-rms*

Image saving code

```
$slider = new Slider();
         if($request->hasFile('slider')) {
            // image that inserted
            $image = $request->file('slider');
            $img = time(). '.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image->move('images/slider-rms/',$img);

            $slider->image = $image;
         }
        $slider->save();
```

Comment: try   <img src="{{asset('images/slider-rms/'.$slider->image)}}" class="d-block w-100"  alt="...">

Comment: dosen't work :(

Comment: check inspect element what url generated from the code

Comment: I picked one image and printed the name $slider->image and printed it. its showing name "C:\xampp\tmp\php4641.tmp" , the saved name is 1633760815.jpg and my image saving code

Comment: if($request->hasFile('slider')) {
            // image that inserted
            $image = $request->file('slider');
            $img = time(). '.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image->move('images/slider-rms/',$img);

            $slider->image = $image;
         }
        $slider->save();